# login issue in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

i want code to check whether the user in logged in or not. I get replied with context that to use `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`. But i do not know how to set the username in servlet so that it is further called by `getUserPrincipal()`

Thank in advance

Comment: If you're using a stateless design, you'll have to pass the user info on every page.  Stateful, then you'll be sticking the user info into the session...

Comment: did you already add login-conf and security-constraint information to your web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a user via [getUserPrincipal](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()), you need to authenticate using container-managed authentication. This usually (always?) involves setting security constraints and authentication mechanisms in your `web.xml`. There are several [examples in the JEE5 tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html). How usernames/passwords are registered is an implementation detail that will depend on the servlet container and how it is configured.